# Why does Cassandra OR WHERE clause not work

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am querying the data from "`countries`" table with `or where` clause but it is giving me the below error.

`line 1:49 mismatched input 'OR' expecting EOF (...countries WHERE alpha2Code = 'PAK' [OR]...)`

Here is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE alpha2Code = 'PAK' OR alpha3Code = 'PAK' allow filtering;
```

How can i achieve the task to get data with `OR WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cassandra doesn't support OR and you will need to implement the logic in the code by making multiple codes to achieve what you are trying above
2. Be warned about the use of allow filtering - not a good practice as you are not querying against a column which is filterable by design.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have followed your suggestion, i'll take care of using allow filtering in future as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra doesn't support the OR operator. Use a disjunction in your code.